# Is this an error in SQL Server's documentation for ROLLBACK?

Tags: sql-server, transaction, rollback, documentation

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/rollback-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is the SQL Server's document talking about the `ROLLBACK` statement. On that page it states that the syntax of it is as follows:

```
ROLLBACK { TRAN | TRANSACTION }   
     [ transaction_name | @tran_name_variable  
     | savepoint_name | @savepoint_variable ]   
[ ; ]
```

Apparently the stuff inside square brackets are optional and it seems you should choose one from `TRAN` or `TRASACTION`. But in fact you can completely omit both and `ROLLBACK` is a perfectly valid statement. Is this an error or intentionally?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` documentation is correct, albeit not clear without additional context.

`ROLLBACK` is shorthand for the similar [`ROLLBACK WORK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/rollback-work-transact-sql) statement rather than `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`. Below is an excerpt from the `ROLLBACK WORK` doc page:

> ROLLBACK [ WORK ]   [ ; ]
>
> This statement functions identically to ROLLBACK TRANSACTION except
> that ROLLBACK TRANSACTION accepts a user-defined transaction name.
> With or without specifying the optional WORK keyword, this ROLLBACK
> syntax is ISO-compatible.
>
> When nesting transactions, ROLLBACK WORK always rolls back to the
> outermost BEGIN TRANSACTION statement and decrements the @@TRANCOUNT
> system function to 0.

Note the same applies to the similar [`COMMIT TRANSACTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/commit-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`COMMIT WORK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/commit-work-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statements.